# Transmit operations performed on select element to corresponding select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I may convert an ordinary select Field to select2

```
$("#myInputFieldID").select2();
```

While somewhere else in my code, executed before the transfer, I define a method that performs an notification on the original select.

```
$.notify($("#myInputFieldID"), "myNotification", {position: "top right", autoHideDelay: 2000});
```

What can I do to redirect the notification to the corresponding select2 (in case it IS converted)?

---

The same accounts to, for example, changing of the select element's css.

Performing an

```
$("#myInputFieldID").css("background-color","red");
```

does not have an effect on the background color of the `span` Element that corresponds to our select element.

How do I change that?

Comment: Do you have a demo available?